# Deserializing different messages (With shared data) from single topic with Spring Kafka

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

**TL;DR**
How to use `@KafkaListener` with `@KafkaHandler` to map one topic to different handlers based on property, mapped to concrete object?

**Details:**

I have a single topic, which contains different messages. Messages are in the format of

```
{type: 1, data1:"foo"}
{type: 2, data2:"bar"}
```

I would preferably want to consume them via single listener like so

```
// Irrelevant code ommited
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Type1Pojo.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Type2Pojo.class)
})
abstract class BasePojo {int type;}
@JsonTypeName("1")
class Type1Pojo extends BasePojo {}
@JsonTypeName("2")
class Type2Pojo extends BasePojo {}

@KafkaListener(containerFactory = "containerFactory")
class Listener {
    @KafkaHandler
    public void handle(Type1Pojo obj, final ConsumerRecordMetadata metadata);

    @KafkaHandler
    public void handle(Type2Pojo obj, final ConsumerRecordMetadata metadata);
}
```

With the following configuration

```
    @Bean
    public JsonDeserializer<BasePojo> jsonDeserializer(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        var jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<BasePojo>(objectMapper);
        // Without this, JsonDeserializer@543 aka 'public T deserialize(String topic, @Nullable byte[] data)'
        // would fail the assertion @554->No headers available and no default type provided
        jsonDeserializer.setTypeResolver((topic, data, headers) -> objectMapper.constructType(BasePojo.class));
        return jsonDeserializer;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, BasePojo> consumerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties, JsonDeserializer<BasePojo> jsonDeserializer) {
        var consumerProperties = kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties();
        var kafkaConsumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, BasePojo>(consumerProperties);
        kafkaConsumerFactory.setValueDeserializer(jsonDeserializer);
        return kafkaConsumerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, BasePojo>> containerFactory(ConsumerFactory<String, BasePojo> consumerFactory) {
        var kafkaListenerContainerFactory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, BasePojo>();
        kafkaListenerContainerFactory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        return kafkaListenerContainerFactory;
    }
```

but the error now is `Could not resolve method parameter at ... : No suitable resolver`
Which is the problem that I am unable to solve - Neither JsonSubtype works (Despite ObjectMapper correctly mapping the concrete class) nor my poor man's TypeResolver (Which resolves class correctly).

`InvocableHandlerMethod` which throws this exception is seeing the message as `GenericMessage [payload=Type1Pojo]` so it's not like the correct class is not passed down...

Versions:

```
spring-kafka:2.7.6
spring-boot-starter:2.5.4
```

Tested via testcontainers

Answer (score 0):

I actually haven't try this, but I think `type` parameter should be a `string` rather than a `int` and also you are missing the `name` parameter inside `@JsonSubTypes.Type`

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Type1Pojo.class, name = "1"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Type2Pojo.class, name = "2")
})
abstract class BasePojo {String type;}
@JsonTypeName("1")
class Type1Pojo extends BasePojo {}
@JsonTypeName("2")
class Type2Pojo extends BasePojo {}
```

Your data should be

```
{type: "1", data1:"foo"}
{type: "2", data2:"bar"}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried this as well - it's not registered by JsonDeserializer